# exec function: import unknown in class definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, python-import

I want to use Python files to configure a program. The files will be read via `exec`. Part of the configuration are class definitions:

config.py

```py
import collections as col  # module alias does not matter

a = col.defaultdict()  # works as expected

class Foo:
    b = col.defaultdict()  # causes NameError: name 'col' is not defined
```

main.py

```py
CONFIG = {}

with open('config.py') as f:
    exec(f.read(), None, CONFIG)
```

Now, when running *main.py* I'll have the problem that outside of the class definition the imported module is known but inside it is not. Why and is there a workaround?

Comment: Why `exec` ? Why not assign the output of `f.read()` to a variable?

Comment: Why not just *import* the module?

Comment: I just re-typed the contents of your config.py into an empty IPython shell running Python 3.7.3 and it works just fine.

Comment: @techouse, yes, I think it's safe to say that `config.py` will work if run in an ordinary shell. The question is why it doesn't run specifically when executed with `exec`.

Comment: Because of the `None` argument to `exec`, free variables in the `class` statement are looked up in the global scope of `main.py`, not `config.py`. `col` and `a`, for reasons not entirely clear to me, are being assigned to the *local* scope.

Comment: I gues you may omit both `None` and `CONFIG` in exec to execute `config.py` in the current scope OR add `globals()['col'] = col` right after import statement in `config.py`.

Comment: @chepner: A simple `import` does not do the trick, because the configuration file is to be given via command line argument and thus may differ each time. But using `importlib.util.module_from_spec` etc. works. Thanks for pointing out the `None` problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [exec's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec),

> If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

So your config.py code is equivalent to

```
class SomeClass:
    import collections as col
    a = col.defaultdict()
    class Foo:
        b = col.defaultdict()
```

This is a problem because, according to [Resolution of Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names),

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block[.]

`col` is defined in the class block of the implicit `SomeClass`. This variable's scope is limited to that class block only; even blocks inside that block, such as `class Foo:`, can't access it.

One possible solution is to pass the same object for `globals` and `locals` so that your code is *not* executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

```
exec(f.read(), CONFIG, CONFIG)
```

Comment: I think this answer explains everything. Thank you.